# Passing ID in two different select function into 1 const function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 different select function that I'll use and get the id from the two different select and pass it into the 1 main function. But I have problem with getting the id from the select function.

What is the correct way on how to pass the id of `cat_id` and `role_id` into the `getMyMode(a,b)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#cat").change(function() {

    let cat_id = $(this).val();
    getMyMode(cat_id);

  });

  $("#role").change(function() {
    let role_id = $(this).val();
    getMyMode(role_id);
  });

});
const getMyMode = (a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <label class="form-label"> Category</label>
  <select class="form-control mb-3" id="cat">
    <option value="99" hidden> Choose Category</option>
    <option value="0">Cat 1</option>
    <option value="1">Cat 2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <label class="form-label"> Role</label>
  <select class="form-control mb-3" id="role">
    <option value="99" hidden>Choose Role</option>
    <option value="23">Role 1</option>
    <option value="24">Role 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You may pass either of the value as `undefined` and maintain other values in the global variable. Or simply access the value using `querySelector` and pass as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this

```js
const getMyMode = (a, b) => { console.log(a, b); };

$(function() { // when page has loaded

  $("#cat, #role").on("change", function() { // when either has changed
    let role_id = $("#role").val();
    let cat_id = $("#cat").val();
    getMyMode(cat_id,role_id);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <label class="form-label"> Category</label>
  <select class="form-control mb-3" id="cat">
    <option value="99" hidden> Choose Category</option>
    <option value="0">Cat 1</option>
    <option value="1">Cat 2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <label class="form-label"> Role</label>
  <select class="form-control mb-3" id="role">
    <option value="99" hidden>Choose Role</option>
    <option value="23">Role 1</option>
    <option value="24">Role 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: may I know if possible, why do we use `$(function()` instead of using `$("#cat, #role").on("change", function() ` on the first line ?

Comment: `$(function() {` identical in functionality but is shorter than `$(document).ready(function() {` it is not related to the rest of the code. It is to make sure the elements are available before adding the event Listener. You had this in your original code, I just shortened it

Comment: tq for the explanations :)